# "backup" server in traefik backend

Tags: backup, traefik

I'm trying to find functionality known as **"backup"** in nginx or haproxy world. Server will be used only if all active backend servers no longer respond ( healthcheck failed ). I don't see it in docs, but maybe I'm overlooking something?
If there is an option to switch to different backend on error condition, that would help too.

I'd like to understand how will be weight = 0 implemented in traefik 1.6. If server is completely ignored even if remaining servers are no longer available.

Comment: Hey @user1788784 - Did you happen to get a solution? I was just experimenting with exactly this and trawled the docs but can't find anything.

Comment: Didn't get any response, used haproxy instead.